# Extract values from array of json elements in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

Im trying to extract an array of values from an array of objects in Postgresql, essentially map over the array and extract.

For instance I have a value of:

```
[{"id":123,"quantity":4,"amount":180},
 {"id":563,"quantity":1,"amount":675},
 {"id":563,"quantity":1,"amount":875},
 ...]
```

And I would like to extract just the amounts in an array, e.g:
`[180,675,875...]`

Is there a simple way of doing this in postgres?

Thank you for any help in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `jsonb_array_elements` to extract the array into a set of JSON values then reaggregate your array using `array_agg` :

```
select array_agg(elm->>'amount')
from mytable t
CROSS JOIN jsonb_array_elements(t.my_json) elm
group by my_json
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/pLKJeM6W)